# How to prove the following function is independent of z?

Tags: special-functions

I series expanded the following expression in Mathematica and the result is independent of z:
$$(1-z)^{-a }\left(\, _2F_1(1,-a ;1-a ;1-z)+\, _2F_1\left(1,a ;a+1;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-1\right)-(1-z)^{a } \left(\, _2F_1\left(1,-a ;1-a ;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)+\, _2F_1(1,a ;a +1;1-z)-1\right)$$

I was trying to find some relations of the hypergeometric function to prove this, but I cannot find any. Anyone know what relation of the hypergeometric function is useful in proving this?

Comment: what does $_2F_1$ mean?

Comment: @GregoryGrant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series

Comment: This looks like a job for [Kummer's solutions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.10), probably combined with the [contiguous relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Gauss.27_contiguous_relations)

Comment: Maybe taking a step back and posting how you got to this expression will make a result independent of $z$ more obvious (if the result should be independent of $z$).